# Problems when making Array of struct and collate words

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I just got an exercise of programming an array of struct of 2(or more) books with specified variables. Insert variables from keyboard and then find out if Publisher is "Kim Dong" then change the price of Book to 0.

Here is my code [I think something is wrong in collating step but cannot find out why :((]:

```
typedef struct book {
    char *author[2000];
    char *id[2000];
    char *name[2000];
    int *price;
    char *publisher[2000];
} sach;

main() 
{   
    int i;
    sach Books[10];

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Nhap thong tin cua sach thu %d:\n", i+1);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", &Books[i].name);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", &Books[i].author);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", &Books[i].id);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &Books[i].price);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", &Books[i].publisher);
    }
    char NXB[8] ="KimDong";

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while( ((int)NXB[j]) == ((int)Books[i].publisher[j]) )
        {
            j++;
        }
        if(j == 6)
        {
            Books[i].price = 0;
        }   
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("\nTen sach: %s", Books[i].name);
        printf("\nID sach la: %s", Books[i].id);
        printf("\nTac gia la: %s", Books[i].author);
        printf("\nNXB la: %s", Books[i].publisher);
        printf("\nGia sach la: %d", Books[i].price);
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Posting `i think something is wrong in collating step but cannot findout why` is not a problem statement.  What should it do, what does it do and what have you done (debugger for example) to ascertain that there is a fault and approximately where it is.

Comment: The formatting of everything inside the second `for(i=0;i<2;i++)` loop is totally unreadable. Consider to do the formatting like in your C textbook. The formatting of the first `for(i=0;i<2;i++)` loop is not much better.

Answer (score 0):

For string comparison use `strcmp(str1,str2)`.

Note that if `str1` is equal to `str2`, the return value will be 0. Contrary to the usual behavior of similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you actually want, but it's probably something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct book {

  char author[2000];
  char id[2000];
  char name[2000];
  int  price;
  char publisher[2000];
}sach;

int main() {

  int i;
  sach Books[10];
  for (i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    printf("Nhap thong tin cua sach thu %d:\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%s", &Books[i].name);
    scanf("%s", &Books[i].author);
    scanf("%s", &Books[i].id);
    scanf("%d", &Books[i].price);
    scanf("%s", &Books[i].publisher);
  }

  char NXB[8] = "KimDong";

  for (i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    while ((NXB[j]) == (Books[i].publisher[j])) {
      j++;
    }
    if (j == 6) {
      Books[i].price = 0;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    printf("\nTen sach: %s", Books[i].name);
    printf("\nID sach la: %s", Books[i].id);
    printf("\nTac gia la: %s", Books[i].author);
    printf("\nNXB la: %s", Books[i].publisher);
    printf("\nGia sach la: %d", Books[i].price);
  }
}
```

`fflush(stdin)` is useless BTW.

The other answer concerning `strcmp` probably applies too here.

There is still room for improvement.